# Button vertical alignemnt inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I want to align vertically a button inside DIV using bootstrap.
So far the button is inside the div and in the same line but seems to be a bit lower.
Here is the code

```
<div class="alert alert-info "  role="alert" ><div style="display:inline">Hello</div> <div style="float:right; display: inline-block;"><a class="btn btn-info " target="_blank" href="">Preview</a></div></div>
```

see the screenshot  [here](http://postimg.org/image/5tmpngvf5/)

Comment: can we have your CSS too please along with a fiddle link?

Comment: Your button is on the same line as your text, the button is just 'bigger'. Add a height to your text to make them the same height.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsbin.com/qipiya/1/edit

Comment: try line-height to make it vertical middle

Comment: for the CSS I am just using bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @HashemQolami Better but the text is not in center vertically

Comment: @bourax But the question doesn't say that it should be, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8qhsbawe/1/

```
.alert-info span {
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this is what I need, to fix the text height

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you need anything else?